# how to get signal strength in android by clicking a button not listening all the time to a listener?

Tags: android

I want to create a method so when I wanted to call it and get the signal strength of my phone I'm totally aware of ordinary way of getting signal strength using PhoneStateListener.

I couldn't find way to access for my problem but I'm sure there is a way for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a variable and let the listener change its value every time it's fired. When you click the button you should just display this variable's value. Hope this helps.

Comment: my idea is to create an API like lib for myself , but your suggestion is very true.

Comment: Is the listener called when it is initialized? Otherwise there might be a short moment when the variable doesn't have a value.

Comment: This situation can be dealt with, for example showing a Toast if a value is not initialized, like when you're trying to access your location in Google Maps when it's just started.